# Executando uma função após selecionar um item na caixa de seleção dupla duallistbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando uma caixa de seleção dupla, [bootstrap4-duallistbox](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Dual-Select-Boxes-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Dual-Listbox/) onde o usuário vai mover para a direita quais as frutas ele deseja.

Minha intenção é executar uma função após o usuário selecionar uma fruta, para exibir o bloco com a class .card que esta escondida com display none, caso o usuário demarque todas as opções, o bloco de código voltará a ficar escondido.

```js
$('.duallistbox').bootstrapDualListbox({
  nonSelectedListLabel: 'Selecione as as frutas',
  selectedListLabel: 'Frutas selecionadas',
  filterTextClear: 'Mostrar todas',
  filterPlaceHolder: 'Buscar',
  moveSelectedLabel: 'Mover fruta selecionada',
  moveAllLabel: 'Selecionar todas as frutas',
  removeSelectedLabel: 'Remover fruta selecionada',
  removeAllLabel: 'Remover todas as frutas',
  infoText: 'Frutas {0}',
  infoTextEmpty: 'Nenhuma fruta selecionada',
  infoTextFiltered: '<span class="label label-warning">Encontrado</span> {0} de {1}',
  preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
  moveOnSelect: false
});

$('select.dual').on('change', function() {
  //console.log($(this).length);
})
```

```css
.card {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}

.card p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap4-duallistbox/4.0.1/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap4-duallistbox/4.0.1/bootstrap-duallistbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="duallistbox">
  <select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="duallistbox" class="dual" name="frutas">
    <option value="abacaxi">Abacaxi</option>
    <option value="acerola">Acerola</option>
    <option value="amora">Amora</option>
    <option value="cupuacu">Cupuaçu</option>
    <option value="framboesa">Framboesa</option>
    <option value="laranja">Laranja</option>
    <option value="morango">Morango</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <p>Card que será exibido quando houver pelo menos uma fruta selecionada</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

O evento é aplicado à mesma classe utilizada para criar o duallistbox. então troque o código

```
$('select.dual').on('change', function() {
    //console.log($(this).length);
});
```

por

```
$('.duallistbox').on('change', function() {
    //console.log($(this).length);
})
```

```js
$('.duallistbox').bootstrapDualListbox({
  nonSelectedListLabel: 'Selecione as as frutas',
  selectedListLabel: 'Frutas selecionadas',
  filterTextClear: 'Mostrar todas',
  filterPlaceHolder: 'Buscar',
  moveSelectedLabel: 'Mover fruta selecionada',
  moveAllLabel: 'Selecionar todas as frutas',
  removeSelectedLabel: 'Remover fruta selecionada',
  removeAllLabel: 'Remover todas as frutas',
  infoText: 'Frutas {0}',
  infoTextEmpty: 'Nenhuma fruta selecionada',
  infoTextFiltered: '<span class="label label-warning">Encontrado</span> {0} de {1}',
  preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
  moveOnSelect: false
});

$('.duallistbox').on('change', function() {
    console.log("duallistbox");
  //console.log($(this).length);
})
```

```css
.card {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}

.card p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap4-duallistbox/4.0.1/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap4-duallistbox/4.0.1/bootstrap-duallistbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="duallistbox">
  <select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="duallistbox" class="dual" name="frutas">
    <option value="abacaxi">Abacaxi</option>
    <option value="acerola">Acerola</option>
    <option value="amora">Amora</option>
    <option value="cupuacu">Cupuaçu</option>
    <option value="framboesa">Framboesa</option>
    <option value="laranja">Laranja</option>
    <option value="morango">Morango</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <p>Card que será exibido quando houver pelo menos uma fruta selecionada</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Não deu certo não, eu adicionei $(".card").show(); para exibir o card, mas quando eu clico sobre ele, sem mover para a direita o card já é mostrado, o correto é exibir somente quando a fruta selecionada for movida para a direita "Frutas selecionadas"